# How to set up a production server environment for a Scala Lift web application?

Tags: scala, lift

I am going to need to set up a production server to host some Scala Lift web services and applications but I've never dealt with JavaEE/servlet technologies. Could you point to a Scala/Lift-specific HOWTO on setting up a production server or, if you don't know of such a publication, explain it in more-or-less simple way?

Answer (score 1):

Lift runs on any regular servlet container; so there's nothing particularly Lift-specific you need to do when building you're environment. That being said, chapter 15 of Lift in Action should help you out with the more general case of taking a Lift application to deployment.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The question is not really about taking a Lift application to deployment but to prepare a server for this. A quick intro into basics of servlet containers and setting them up maybe.

Comment: The content I referenced walks you through exactly that... choosing a servlet container and what specialisation's are supported and what are not.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are asking this, but you can set up server with Debian Lenny to serve Lift application using [this](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Debian_Lenny_install_guide) reference in the Lift wiki, with a Jetty container, and PostgreSQL database. Usually the setup varies depending on the requirements of your application (which database, etc), so eventually will need to provide more information on what you need to setup for a given environment. Apart from this, reinforcing what Tim Perret said, chapter 15 in his [book](http://www.manning.com/perrett/) is really good detailing the servlet container to choose, and deployment techniques, tools, and options.

Comment: This looks a lot like the answer. But I am surprised by it to recommend Jetty as a production server (covered with Apache though). I supposed Jetty is for development only and I need to set up something like Glassfish or Tomcat for production.

Comment: You can find here http://www.mogilowski.net/lang/en-us/2010/12/11/install-tomcat-7-on-debian-lenny-with-virtual-hosts-and-apache2-integration/ an excellent introduction to the setup of Tomcat 7 in Debian Lenny. In my case I use Tomcat 7 for deployment in production, but you can perfectly use Jetty as well (or any other container with servlet 3.0 specification). I would use Glassfish if your application needs Java EE support.

Comment: I would use Glassfish if the application needs Java EE support. Details on installing in Debian are here: http://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/run_glassfish_v3_as_a